# CloudKit: fetching records that have a certain element in a list attribute

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, cloudkit

I was wondering whether it is possible to form an `NSPredicate` that would do the following in CloudKit:

Suppose that I have some record type **A**. Suppose that **A** has some attribute *b* that is of type `[CKReference]`. Let *c* be some element of type `CKReference` that could be in *b*.

I wish to query for all records of type **A** that have *c* in the list *b*. Is it possible to do this with `NSPredicate`?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

I basically want to do this ([CloudKit - NSPredicate for finding all records that contain specified CKReference in a reference list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189158/cloudkit-nspredicate-for-finding-all-records-that-contain-specified-ckreferenc?rq=1)), but in Swift 3. I'm having trouble finding good resources online that explain how to use `contains` in an `NSPredicate`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what ended up working for me, in terms of the variables I used in the question:

`let`*c*`= CKReference(recordID: userRecordID!, action: .none)`

`let joinedPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS %@",`*b*`,`*c*`)`.

`let joinedQuery = CKQuery(recordType:`**A**`, predicate: joinedPredicate)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var predicates = [NSPredicate]()
predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "("your key" CONTAINS[cd]%@)", filterString))

and initialising CKrefrence in swift 

let reference = CKReference(recordID: example.recordID, action: .deleteSelf)
```

you can create CKReference object by using-- let reference = CKReference(recordID: example.recordID, action: .deleteSelf) where example.recordId will be record Id from your CloudKit and after creating you need to have your filter using predicate where predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "("your key" CONTAINS[cd]%@)", filterString)) filter string will contains reference of your created CKReference object –

Comment: Please explain your solution not just paste the code.

Comment: you can create CKReference object by using-- let reference = CKReference(recordID: example.recordID, action: .deleteSelf) where example.recordId will be record Id from your CloudKit and after creating you need to have your filter using predicate  where predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "("your key" CONTAINS[cd]%@)", filterString)) filter string will contains reference of your created CKReference object

Comment: I meant add to your answer..This was flagged as low quality post.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What is the meaning of `cd` in `CONTAINS[cd]`?

Comment: this is key to filter in NSPredicate contains will check if it is containing in that array or list NSPredicate can be made case insensitive by including a [c] (in square brackets) after the comparison operator (e.g. BEGINSWITH[c]). You can make the comparison diacritic insensitive using a [d] modifier or case and diacritic insensitive with a [cd] modifier.

Comment: I'm actually still having some issues. In my code I have `let joinedPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "JOINED_BY CONTAINS %@", userRef)`. I get the error message: `"Server Rejected Request" (15/2000); server message = "Unknown field 'JOINED_BY'"`. I verified in my CloudKit dashboard that there is a field `joinedBy`, and I verified that my constants file has `JOINED_BY = "joinedBy"`. This field is of type `[CKReference]`. Does `CONTAINS` work with `CKReference`?

Comment: Oh, I think I figured it out! `let joinedPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS %@", JOINED_BY, userRef)`